# Hide div depending on dropdown menu doesnt work probebly

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have drop-down menu in checkout
It's for multiple billing addresses.

```
<select name="thwma-billing-alt" id="thwma-billing-alt" class="select " data-allow_clear="true" data-placeholder="60 street, postcode 33445">
<option value="address_0" selected="selected">60 street, postcode 33445</option>
<option value="address_1">30 street, postcode 33333</option>
<option value="add_address">Add New Address</option>
```

And there is a div `woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper` where it show the text fields

I'm using this method to show the div ONLY when the user select Add New Address from drop down.

```
function load_scripts(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('select[name="thwma-billing-alt"]').on('change', function() {
                    if( this.value == "add_address" ){
                        $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").show();
                    }else{
                        $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").hide(); 
                    }
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'load_scripts', 10, 1 );
```

**My problem is; when I load the page it doesnt work until I select something from the drop down**

What I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I tried it like this

```
function load_scripts(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $('select[name="thwma-billing-alt"]').trigger('on');
 $('select[name="thwma-billing-alt"]').on('change', function() {
                    if( this.value == "add_address" ){
                        $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").show();
                    }else{
                        $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").hide(); 
                    }
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'load_scripts', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Of course it only works after you changed the selected option - because your code adds a _change_ handler. You can _trigger_ this event manually using https://api.jquery.com/trigger/ to get the callback function to execute.

Comment: @CBroe Should I trigger the whole code? or just this `$(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").show();`

Comment: No, you should trigger the event on the element. There _are_ examples on the page I referred you to.

Comment: @CBroe like this? `$('select[thwma-billing-alt]').trigger('change');` I added this line

Comment: That's not how you actually selected the element before, when you added the event handler.

Comment: @CBroe `$('select[name="thwma-billing-alt"]').trigger('change', function()` like this?

Comment: @CBroe I tried this too `$('select[name="thwma-billing-alt".val('address_0')]').trigger('change', function()`

Comment: @CBroe you will leave me stuck like this :'( I tried everything...

Comment: No need for an extra callback function, and no sense in making `.val('address_0')` part of the attribute selector. `$('select[name="thwma-billing-alt"]').trigger('on');` should do the job.

Comment: @CBroe I did that, still doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you did it in the wrong place, so show us where you put it. Also, "doesn't work" doesn't work for us, as a problem description. Which option _is_ the selected one, when the page loads?

Comment: @CBroe I'm sorry, okay I edit the question, is it in the right place? when the page loaded it's the first option selected

Comment: No, you are trying to trigger an event that you have no even bound to the element at that point. And it should be `change` instead of `on` (my mistake in that previous comment.)

Comment: @CBroe I tried to put it after this line `$('select[name="thwma-billing-alt"]').on('change', function() {` can you give me a hint? I'm sorry to bother you, I'm new to jquery

Comment: Did you correct the `on` vs `change` mishap? _"when the page loaded it's the first option selected"_ - so the drop-down should _not_ show then, is that not what is happening?

Comment: Yes I changed it to this `$('select[name="thwma-billing-alt"]').trigger('change');` and @CBroe put it after this line `$('select[name="thwma-billing-alt"]').on('change' ,function() {` and by default when I load the page it land on the first option from drop down, but it doesn't hide the div until I select something else from dropdown, then go back to the first option

Comment: I also tried to replace the whole line, with the new trigger, and it stop working

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/zarp3cbg/

Comment: @CBroe For some reason when I cleared the cart and try to make new order it works :D you are awesome :') finally after a week trying